# iOS: any way to check if a property name is private or reserved name?

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties, private-members

Recently I had a problem when I upload an app, the App Uploader told me I used a private property called 'contentId' which is a private property in Core Data managed object, what I did is to create a protocol that has a 'contentId' property and make one of my core data managed object subclass implements that protocol, and in the getter of 'contentId' it returns its object id, I don't know if I use 'contentId' directly in managed object subclass, whether or not it warns me at that time, but I wonder is there a way to make sure my classes do not use private properties, before trying to upload and let the app uploader tells me, as sometimes it is not possible to make change at the final step.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the app validator (it's in the organiser, if memory serves) to check that it gives the same result? If it does then I guess an answer would be to use that periodically and thereby not leave this stuff until the final step. Though hopefully a better answer will be forthcoming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, I suppose you could test as you develop whether

```
[self respondsToSelector:@selector(setSomePotentiallyPrivateProperty)];
```

before declaring the property.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to do this every time when I add properties to a class.

Comment: Sure I would imagine not. Best I could think of though